# Recommended gems for accessing Fusion Tables API using OAuth 2.0 on a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-fusion-tables

I have a Rails 3 application, and I need to access a user's Fusion Table using OAuth 2.0. I am not using OAuth in the app for user authentication, we have our own users database managed with devise.

I have been looking around, and it seems that there is only one [library for handling Fusion Tables API](https://github.com/tokumine/fusion_tables). However, this library only supports Authlogic and user/pass login, not OAuth, as it inherits from the [GData gem](https://github.com/tokumine/GData).

There is a [google library for Ruby that handles OAuth](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/wiki/OAuth2), but it does not abstract Fusion Tables behaviour.

I have also found a Rails-specific gem [that also handles OAuth](https://github.com/pelle/oauth-plugin), as well as an [omniauth strategy for google oauth2](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2).

My question is: has anyone had any experience with any of these libraries? Which ones would you recommend?

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry I haven't had experience with these, but I might start looking at them, as I am keen to explore fusiontables/rails integration.  I'm confused about the best approach - should data be left in fusiontables, replicated in Rails, or kept just in Rails?  I guess ultimately I'm wondering what's the advantage of FusionTables integation - aren't we all better off with just Gmap/RoR integration?  What are you hoping to get from FusionTables that you don't get from Gmap/RoR?